# Setting property values based on other properties of same object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code.

```
var myApp = {
    nav               : $('#top_nav .nav'),
    primary_navs      : $('#top_nav .nav').find('> li'),
    secondary_navs    : $('#top_nav .nav').find('> li').find('.secondary > li')
}
```

This works, but I would prefer not to repeat the jquery selector functions over and over. I would like to do,

```
    primary_navs      : nav.find('> li')
```

but this gives me "nav is not defined". I have tried `myApp.nav`, and `this`, but clearly neither works the way I think they should. How can I refer to properties of an object when defining new properties of the same object?

Comment: Use a function that returns an object

Comment: @jac what do you mean

Comment: if you know the path to the children elements like 'li' wont it be better to not "find them" . And just reference to them straight would save on performance.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I posted an example as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Cache the variable

```
var $nav = $('#top_nav .nav');
```

Then you can use it multiple times in your code

```
var $nav = $('#top_nav .nav'),
    $childrenLi = $nav.children('li');

var myApp = {
    nav               : $nav ,
    primary_navs      : $childrenLi ,
    secondary_navs    : $childrenLi.find('.secondary > li')
}
```

You can also use `children` to get the immediate children.

`$('#top_nav .nav').find('> li')`  same as  `$('#top_nav .nav').children('li')`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object using `new` with an anonymous function:

```
var myApp = new function(){
    this.nav =  $('#top_nav .nav');
    this.primary_navs = this.nav.children('li');
    this.secondary_navs = this.primary_navs.find('.secondary > li')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate it into an anonymous function that executes and returns an object:

```
var myApp = (function($nav) {
    return {
        nav: $nav,
        primary_navs: $nav.find('> li'),
        secondary_navs: $nav.find('> li').find('.secondary > li')
    };
}($('#top_nav .nav')));
```

Answer (score 0):

All the statements when you are declaring the object are evaluated at the same time so you can't use the results of a *previous* attribute for a second. However what you can do is set your MyApp to equal a function that is immediately evaluated and returns an object.

For example

```
var myApp = function() {
   var $nav,  $primary_navs;   
   var $nav = $('#top_nav .nav');
   var $primary_navs = $nav.find('> li');
  return {
    nav: $nav,
    primary_navs:  $primary_navs,
    secondary_navs = $primary_navs.find('.secondary > li')
  }  
}();
```